# Bamboo Artifactory Generic Deploy configuration - how to use bamboo variables in artifactory spec files

Tags: plugins, artifactory, bamboo, specs

I'm using Bamboo 6.3.2 and Artifactory Plugin 2.4.1.
I want to upload artifacts to Artifactory using "specs"
How can I include Bamboo variables?
Right now the variables are ignored.

`

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "Konfig6000/FMZ6000-Konfiguration.zip",
      "target": "{${bamboo.planRepository.branch}}/${bamboo.buildNumber}/FMZ6000-Konfiguration.zip",
      "props": "configversion="+${bamboo.inject.configversion}+";modellversion="+${bamboo.inject.modellversion}
    }
  ]
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The Bamboo variables were expanded correctly for me when using the following specs :

```
    {
        "files": [
            {
              "pattern": "${bamboo.build.working.directory}/BuildOutput/bin/x86/Release",
              "target": "Appx/${bamboo.planRepository.branch}/${bamboo.buildNumber}/"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am using the same Artifactory Plugin version.